# Drupal 8 Module Design Advice

Tags: 8

I am building a simple checkout module and need some advice on how to structure this application.

So far the module consists of:

- `src\Entity\Transaction.php` - Custom entity type for storing **transactions**.
- `src\Form\CartForm.php` - Alters Cart (Cart data stored as a session via `Drupal::service`). On submit, user redirects `src\Controller\PaymentController`.
- `src\Controller\PaymentController.php`:

  - Cart data is pulled from the `Drupal::service`.
  - Cart data (prices, items, etc) is configured the PayPal API.
  - A transaction entity type is created and:

    1. stores serialized cart data inside the transaction entity as a map field,
    2. stores data from the PayPal API,
    3. transaction is saved.
  - After the transaction is created, the user is redirected to PayPal.
  - Upon successful/unsuccessful payment, data is passed from the PayPal website to the `src\Controller\PaymentController.php` again and transaction entity is updated.

So far it seems pretty logical however, I feel this could be improved structurally.

Currently, a lot is happening in the `PaymentController` (too much code in one file). Is there a component that Symfony or Drupal 8 offers that would split some of this code?

Any other advice on design and structure would be great as well. I don't anticipate using Drupal Commerce. My organization sells a few services and Drupal Commerce seems like it would be overkill.

Comment: If you feel Commerce is overkill, you may look at [Payment](https://www.drupal.org/project/payment), which provides an API for use with other modules.  The [PayPal submodule](https://www.drupal.org/project/paypal_payment) only has a dev release for D8, but this might give you some ideas about how to approach this.